# Are these nonstationary variables?

Tags: correlation, stationarity, spurious-correlation

If I have understood correctly, computing the correlation of two nonstationary variables can lead to spurious results. For example, computing the correlation of two stock price time series would lead to nonsense results if they both are trending upward, right?

What about interest rates in two different countries? Is it meaningful to compute the correlation between them? Obviously, there can be long time periods when the interest rate is high/low, so I guess it is strongly autocorrelated. But even strongly autocorrelated series can be stationary, right?